# How to add ojdbc7 to Java web app by Gradle?

Tags: java, oracle, maven, gradle, build.gradle

My context:

- I build a Java web application what based on Spring Boot
  1.3.5.RELEASE .
- I try to add `ojdcb` to dependencies list but not success.
- I know that Oracle has own Maven repository at
  `http://maven.oracle.com`

This is my `build.gradle` file, Let focus at line 4, 5, 6, 36:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url ("https://maven.oracle.com")
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.5.RELEASE")

    }
}

apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'erp'
    version = '1.0.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    //compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-core")
    compile("com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc7:12.1.0.2")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}
```

IntelliJ IDEA 2016 notice error:

> Warning:***root project 'erp': Web Facets/Artifacts will not be
>   configured properly** Details:
>   org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all
>   dependencies for configuration ':runtime'. Caused by:
>   org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not
>   find com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc7:12.1.0.2. Required by:
>       :erp:unspecified*

[image]

(Related links: http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/MAVEN/config_maven_repo.htm#MAVEN9015
https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/entry/how_to_get_oracle_jdbc
https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/entry/oracle_maven_repository_instructions_for
)

Help me add `ojdbc` to dependencies list by Gradle, thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Oracle database 12c

**(1)** Download `ojdbc7.jar` at Oracle homepage.

**(2)** Run command

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=ojdbc7.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc7 -Dversion=12.1.0.1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

**(3)** Add to `build.gradle`

```
compile('com.oracle:ojdbc7:12.1.0.1')
```

Answer (score 14):

Gradle currently can't handle the redirects needed by the realm-based 
SSO mechanism used by Oracle's maven repo.

A [workaround](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gradle-dev/G8X_41lOIlU) is to use this URL instead

```
url "https://www.oracle.com/content/secure/maven/content"
```

In addition, you need to supply credentials for authentication.

Here's a minimal example:

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()

    maven {

       url "https://www.oracle.com/content/secure/maven/content"

       credentials {
         username = '<Oracle Account email address>'
         password = '<Oracle Account password>'
       }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc7:12.1.0.2'
}
```

I have a github repo with full example including a way of encrypting the password using maven's `settings.xml` and `settings-security.xml`: [example-gradle-oracle](https://github.com/robin-a-meade/example-gradle-oracle)

*I am adding = after username and password as mentioned in Gradle AuthenticationSupported.java file*

Comment: This works for me. Also, as noted by @Opal in his answer, in the question's example `build.gradle` file, the Oracle repository is defined at the wrong location. It needs to be defined in the top-level `repositories { ...}` section, not inside `buildscript { ... }`.

Answer (score 5):

Your build.gradle will work if you replace:

```
maven {
    url ("https://maven.oracle.com")
}
```

to:

```
maven {
    url "https://www.oracle.com/content/secure/maven/content"
    name "maven.oracle.com"
    credentials {
       username 'email@mail.com'
       password 'your password'
    }
}
```

Credetials from Oracle Registration page: https://profile.oracle.com/myprofile/account/create-account.jspx.

Additionally:

To place authentication data outside of project home, you can edit configuration file `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`:

```
mavenOracleUsername=email@mail.com
mavenOraclePassword=your password
```

and use it in configuration like:

```
 credentials {
    username mavenOracleUsername
    password mavenOraclePassword
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added the http://nexus.saas.hand-china.com/content/repositories/rdc/ repo and work

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    //Add this repo
    maven {
        url "http://nexus.saas.hand-china.com/content/repositories/rdc/"
    }
}
...
dependencies {
   ....
   compile group: 'com.oracle', name: 'ojdbc7', version: '12.1.0.2'
}
```