# installing jar in local mvn repository succeeds, but still cannot be found

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have executed:

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.oracle 
-DartifactId=ojdbc7 -Dfile=ojdbc7.jar -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=12.1.0.2
```

The installation succeeds...

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ---------------------------< XXXX:XXXX >----------------------------
[INFO] Building XXXX 18.2.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) @ XXXX ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Projects\XXXX-svn\trunk\XXXX\ojdbc7.jar to C:\Users\QXV0615\.m2\repository\com\oracle\ojdbc7\12.1.0.2\ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\QXV0615\AppData\Local\Temp\mvninstall491035374333687338.pom to C:\Users\QXV0615\.m2\repository\com\oracle\ojdbc7\12.1.0.2\ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.096 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-07-06T07:30:13+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But then

mvn install

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ---------------------------< XXXX:XXXX >----------------------------
[INFO] Building XXXX 18.2.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0.2 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.ibm.mq:jms:jar:7.0.1.9 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.993 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-07-06T07:30:26+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project XXXX: Could not resolve dependencies for project XXXX:XXXX:war:18.2.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0.2, com.ibm.mq:jms:jar:7.0.1.9: Failure to find com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0.2 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

The dependency is specified as follows:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

## EDIT

I have also tried

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.oracle 
-DartifactId=ojdbc7 -Dfile=ojdbc7.jar -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=12.1.0.2 -DgeneratePom=true
```

**-DgeneratePom=true**

And it still doesn't find the file!

Comment: How is this a duplicate of the question at the given link..? This specifically asks about the artifact being present in the local repo... Neither the question nor the answers on that post address this...

Comment: @ernest, thanks - perhaps you can actually help, instead of pointing me to an answer that doesn't help one bit.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele I reopened this so now you can provide the correct answer. I expect you to do that, since you've been so involved in this question without actually doing anything really. Now's your chance to shine.

Comment: @Kayaman No, that's wrong. It was closed incorrectly and that's why it was reopened. Thanks. I also want to see the answer, so my responsibility was to challenge the incorrect "duplicate" decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message:

> The POM for com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0.2 is missing, no dependency information available

Your `groupId` is wrong - it should be `com.oracle.jdbc`, and not just `com.oracle` as your snippet (`\`s added to make the example easier to read, they aren't a necessary part of the solution):

```
mvn install:install-file \
    -DgroupId=com.oracle.jdbc \
    -DartifactId=ojdbc7 \
    -Dfile=ojdbc7.jar \
    -Dpackaging=jar \
    -Dversion=12.1.0.2 \
    -DgeneratePom=true
```

Note that you'll still have to do something similar for the jms jar you're missing in the second error method.

Comment: There seems to be both `groupId`s in use. It looks like `com.oracle` is for a jar that's downloaded from Oracle's website and `com.oracle.jdbc` is for one from Oracle's Maven repo. Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37783669/how-to-add-ojdbc7-to-java-web-app-by-gradle

Answer (score 0):

Place the jar in your lib directory and You can use like this .

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.0.2</version>

<systemPath>
${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/ojdbc7.jar
</systemPath>
</dependency>
```