# Unexpected error running Liquibase: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find database driver: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

Tags: gradle, liquibase

This was asked before but did not help because I am using gradle. I have Oracle 12c running in Docker at `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe`.

In my gradle.build I have the following gradle task:

```
task('dev') << {
    println "executing dev"
    liquibase {
        activities {
            main {
                changeLogFile changeLog
                url 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe'
                username 'admin'
                password 'admin'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I added two different jars to `libs/jdbc-oracle.jar` and added `compile files('libs/jdbc-oracle.jar')` but still got the same error. I am using the `gradle liquidbase plugin` version `classpath "org.liquibase:liquibase-gradle-plugin:1.2.4"`

Has anyone had this issue before? How was it resolved?

-------------------Update 1-----------------

I added the following:

`compile ("com.oracle:ojdbc7:12.1.0.1")` in the `buildscript` and tried in the `dependencies` both failed.

Comment: Try: `compile fileTree(dir: "lib", include: "*.jar")`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458661/how-to-use-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-gradle-project

Comment: @user7294900 not sure if you read my question because you gave me a post of the solution I already tried. Thank you for the effort.

Comment: @SaschaFrinken good idea and I just tried it and sadly got the same error.

Comment: @SaschaFrinken this is a springboot application. I am wondering if I should configure it this route. I know in Jhipster it is done this was if I recall correctly.

Comment: Did you add this to your buildscript classpath as well? Maybe you should post your complete build.gradle file

Comment: This seems to be a common issue.  I've spent the entire afternoon trying to get `diffChangeLog` running.  I can't figure out why the task cannot find my SQL Server driver that I've specified on my `buildscript` class path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I had to add the jar manually and use JDBC 7, than add the classpath under main. JDBC 12 gave me errors I found out downgrading should solve the issue here [link to post](http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/liquibase-diff-cannot-find-database-driver)

```
task('dev') << {
    println "executing dev"
    liquibase {
        activities {
            main {
                changeLogFile changeLog
                classpath 'build/libs/jdbc7.jar'
                url 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe'
                username 'admin'
                password 'admin'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but still getting the error in my case.