# How to configure Oracle to Spring boot application

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, gradle

I want to set up spring boot latest project with the Oracle database. i did fw steps
1. Download ojdbc7 12.1.0.1 jar and keep it in "C:\Users\Dasun_09323.m2\repository\com\oracle\ojdbc7".

2.using maven command i installed that jar.
3.added this gradle dependency, compile group: 'cn.easyproject', name: 'ojdbc7', version: '12.1.0.1'.

Than i open the terminal in intelliJ idea and hit gradle build -x test to build the project but BUILD FAILED ..

Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
>   Could not find cn.easyproject:ojdbc7:12.1.0.1.
>   Required by:
>   project :

How to fix this issue ? this ate my 3 days of working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a directory called Lib and upload oracle driver jar into it. then i removed the dependency for the oracle and i just added. this line in under the dependency corner.

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'lib')
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error it looks like you have not added the entry in your .m2 correctly.

Verify that the jar exists in :\Users\Dasun_09323.m2\repository\cn\easyproject

If it exists then you can get the entries from pom.xml file in the dependency and make sure it matches what you are using in gradle.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. actually driver cannot find that is the reason for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")

}
```

Maven

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

to use CrudRepository
more info here https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html

in your application properties

```
# Oracle settings

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522:orcl

spring.datasource.username=HIBERNATE_TEST

spring.datasource.password=HIBERNATE_TEST

spring.datasource.driver.class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

here is a good article on dzone
https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-jpa-hibernate-oracle

Using the oracle driver is answered in this post [How to use Oracle JDBC driver in Gradle project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37458661/1617955)

Comment: You do need oracle driver to connect to oracle

Comment: I did this and above issue came. finally i figure out the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add repository on your project' pom file,  in the repositories tag:

```
  <repository>
        <id>ICM</id>
        <name>ICM project repository</name>
        <url>https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/repo</url>
  </repository>
```